# ASP.net - one label, multiple values

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have a label, `lblmessage`, which I want to assign 4 different values.

```
It should show up like this:
5
4
3
2
```

I know this: `lblmessage.text = "5"` and to assign it another value `lblmessage.text = lblmessage.text + "4"`.

This just puts them next to each other, but how can I get them to show up underneath each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
lblmessage.Text += "<br />4";
```

Although I suggest that you use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like..

```
lblmessage.Text = string.Format("{0}<br/>{1}<br/>{2}<br/>{3}<br/>", "5", "4", "3", "2");
```